# Can people lose movie tickets when buying them with diamonds in Hay Day?

Tags: hay-day

I often get movie tickets in the game Hay Day.

One day I bought some diamonds at a 50% discount.

After I bought them, I no longer see them.

Is this common thing that happens to everyone?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is from official HayDay already;

> [HayDay Facebook Page Post](https://www.facebook.com/HayDayOfficial/photos/a.519327768151795.1073741828.297050457046195/519327984818440/)
>
> The movie ticket is a feature that is assigned to a random group of players and they may appear & disappear from the farms at any time. We hope you get your chance soon! Note: this feature is currently only available on the iOS version of Hay Day.

Anyway, I can wish you luck!

Comment: That's the official statement. However, I've hard reports people stop getting movie tickets after buying lots of diamonds. I stop playing hay day then.

Comment: The iOS only part isn't accurate.  I get them on my Android frequently.  and they did stop for a while despite buying no diamonds  (@JimThio)

Answer (score 1):

I lost my movie tickets after only spending $1.99 for diamonds.  When I asked Supercell about it, I got the same standard answer.